# Layer painting problem

Tags: layers

I have an issue with painting a certain section that has been 'layered' as in, having created a seperate collection from the object in question. Here is a link of an image describing the details: https://www.mediafire.com/view/h0iz7x4l71lmb59/Painting_Problem.png/file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 objects are sharing the same material, and the faces of the big objects are overlapping in the *UV Editor*, you could see it in the *UV Editor* if you select all in *Edit* mode, you need to unwrap with another method, like *Unwrap* > *Smart UV Project* or mark some seams then *Unwrap* > *Unwrap*.